# Power BI report refresh

Tags: sql-server, database, session, powerbi, report

I have a few reports with some of them having more than one tabs. All the tabs reference to the same database, but different tables.

1. My question is when the reports are refreshed, will each report set up a separate session to SQL server database?
2. Will all the tabs in the same report share the same session and refresh in sequential order?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is when the reports are refreshed, will each report set up a separate session to SQL server database?

Datasets are refreshed, not reports.  But yes, each dataset will use its own connections.

> Will all the tabs in the same report share the same session and refresh in sequential order?

Parallel, by default.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-evaluation-configuration